# Sentry performance monitoring with a Ktor server

Tags: performance, kotlin, sentry, ktor

I would like to send performance transactions to Sentry using a Ktor server plugin to track performance metrics for API calls. How can I integrate the Sentry java and kotlin SDKs with Ktor?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to integrate a Ktor server with Sentry performance monitoring.

## Via OpenTelemetry

The Sentry SDK supports exporting OpenTelemetry traces and spans as Sentry transactions and spans.

Add OpenTelemetry tracing to Ktor via OpenTelemetry's [Ktor 1.0](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/ktor/ktor-1.0/library) and [Ktor 2.0](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/ktor/ktor-2.0/library) client and server integrations ([OpenTelemetry Registry for Ktor](https://opentelemetry.io/ecosystem/registry/?s=ktor&component=&language=)).

Then [configure the Sentry SDK and OpenTelemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75946567/430128) to propagate OpenTelemetry traces and spans to Sentry.

## Via the Sentry SDK

Create a custom Ktor plugin to export transactions and spans to Sentry. It may look like this:

```kotlin
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.application.hooks.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import io.ktor.util.pipeline.*
import io.sentry.Breadcrumb
import io.sentry.ITransaction
import io.sentry.Sentry
import io.sentry.SpanStatus
import io.sentry.kotlin.SentryContext
import io.sentry.protocol.Request
import io.sentry.protocol.Response
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

val sentryTransactionKey = AttributeKey<ITransaction>("SentryTransaction")

val SentryPlugin = createApplicationPlugin("SentryPlugin") {
  on(MonitoringEvent(Routing.RoutingCallStarted)) { call ->
    val transaction = Sentry.startTransaction(
      /* name = */ "${call.request.httpMethod.value} ${call.request.path()}",
      /* operation = */ "call",
      /* customSamplingContext = */ CustomSamplingContext().apply {
        this["path"] = call.request.path().lowercase()
      },
      /* bindToScope = */ true
    )
    // customize as necessary
    Sentry.configureScope { scope ->
      scope.addBreadcrumb(Breadcrumb.http(call.request.uri, call.request.httpMethod.value))
      scope.request = Request().apply {
        method = call.request.httpMethod.value
        url = call.request.path()
        queryString = call.request.queryString()
        headers = call.request.headers.toMap()
          .mapValues { (_, v) -> v.firstOrNull() }
      }
      scope.setTag("url", call.request.uri)
      scope.setTag("host", call.request.host())
      scope.user = User().apply {
        // call.authentication
      }
    }
    call.attributes.put(sentryTransactionKey, transaction)
    transaction.startChild("setup", "Call setup")
  }

  on(MonitoringEvent(Routing.RoutingCallStarted)) { call ->
    call.sentryTransactionOrNull()?.let { t ->
      t.latestActiveSpan?.finish(SpanStatus.OK)
      t.setTag("route", call.route.parent.toString())
      t.startChild("processing", "Request processing")
    }
  }

  on(ResponseBodyReadyForSend) { call, content ->
    call.sentryTransactionOrNull()?.let { t ->
      t.latestActiveSpan?.finish(SpanStatus.OK)
      t.startChild("sending", "Sending response")
    }
  }

  on(CallFailed) { call, cause ->
    call.sentryTransactionOrNull()?.apply {
      throwable = cause
    }
  }

  on(ResponseSent) { call ->
    call.sentryTransactionOrNull()?.let { t ->
      t.latestActiveSpan?.finish(SpanStatus.OK)
      Sentry.addBreadcrumb(
        Breadcrumb.http(call.request.uri, call.request.httpMethod.value, call.response.status()?.value)
      )
      t.contexts.setResponse(
        Response().apply {
          headers = call.response.headers.allValues().toMap().mapValues { (_, v) -> v.firstOrNull() }
          statusCode = call.response.status()?.value
        },
      )
      t.finish(SpanStatus.fromHttpStatusCode(call.response.status()?.value, SpanStatus.OK))
    }
  }

  on(SentryContextHook()) { block ->
    block()
  }
}

fun ApplicationCall.sentryTransactionOrNull() =
  if (attributes.contains(sentryTransactionKey)) attributes[sentryTransactionKey] else null

class SentryContextHook : Hook<suspend (suspend () -> Unit) -> Unit> {
  private val phase = PipelinePhase("SentryContext")

  override fun install(
    pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline,
    handler: suspend (suspend () -> Unit) -> Unit
  ) {
    pipeline.insertPhaseBefore(ApplicationCallPipeline.Setup, phase)
    pipeline.intercept(phase) {
      withContext(SentryContext()) {
        handler(::proceed)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The plugin should be installed after `StatusPages` (if used) so that `on(CallFailed)` works correctly.

The plugin configures the `SentryContext` (requires the [Sentry kotlin coroutines extensions](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/enriching-events/scopes/#kotlin-coroutines)) for the request, so that Sentry calls to create child spans or breadcrumbs or other such operations will be attached to the request scope. This scope is also propagated into child coroutines.

It also creates a sampling context which can be used to control sampling for performance monitoring. Example:

```kotlin
Sentry.init { options ->
  ...
  options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0 // default if sampler below returns null
  options.setTracesSampler { context ->
    val samplingContext = context.customSamplingContext
    if (samplingContext != null) {
      // if this is the continuation of a trace, just use that decision
      // (rate controlled by the caller)
      if (context.transactionContext.parentSampled == true) return@setTracesSampler 1.0
      @Suppress("MagicNumber")
      when (samplingContext["path"] as? String) {
        "/healthz" -> 0.001
        // customize as necessary
        else -> null
      }
    } else {
      null
    }
  }
}
```